# Sorting a JSON file for Discord leaderboards

Tags: python, json, dictionary, discord.py

looked around on StackOverflow, didn't find anything that answered my question.
I attempted to do this by doing

```py
async def leaderboard(self, ctx):
    leaderboard = {}
    with open("database.json") as f:
        leaderboard = json.load(f)
    f.close()
    sorted_data = {id: money for id, money in sorted(leaderboard.items(), reverse=True ,key=lambda money: money[1])}
    print(sorted_data)
```

I wanted to make a leaderboard for my Discord guild, and I have the currency of every user stored on a JSON file.

As an example, in the JSON file, they look like:

```
{
"_default": {

"30": {
    "money": 0,
    "userid": 349846310024642560
},
"32": {
    "money": 30861,
    "userid": 228718166602153985
},
"33": {
    "money": 325663,
    "userid": 180688669089202177
}
}
}
```

How can I sort this and grab the 10 or so richest users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this example how to sort the dictionary by `money` key and then print top `x` users:

```
data = {
    "30": {"money": 0, "userid": 349846310024642560},
    "32": {"money": 30861, "userid": 228718166602153985},
    "33": {"money": 325663, "userid": 180688669089202177},
}

richest = sorted(data, key=lambda k: -data[k]["money"])

for k in richest[:2]:  # <-- change to 10 if you want top 10
    print(
        "Money: {:<10} UserId: {}".format(data[k]["money"], data[k]["userid"])
    )
```

Prints:

```
Money: 325663     UserId: 180688669089202177
Money: 30861      UserId: 228718166602153985
```

EDIT: With `_default` key:

```
data = {
    "_default": {
        "30": {"money": 0, "userid": 349846310024642560},
        "32": {"money": 30861, "userid": 228718166602153985},
        "33": {"money": 325663, "userid": 180688669089202177},
    }
}

data = data["_default"]
richest = sorted(data, key=lambda k: -data[k]["money"])

for k in richest[:2]:  # <-- change to 10 if you want top 10
    print(
        "Money: {:<10} UserId: {}".format(data[k]["money"], data[k]["userid"])
    )
```

Comment: This causes an error, unfortunately! I get the error: 

Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'money'

Code so far

```py
leaderboard = {}
        with open("database.json") as f:
            leaderboard = json.load(f)
        f.close()
        print(leaderboard)
        richest = sorted(leaderboard, key=lambda k: -leaderboard[k]["money"])

        for k in richest[:2]:  # <-- change to 10 if you want top 10
            print(
                "Money: {:<10} UserId: {}".format(leaderboard[k]["money"], leaderboard[k]["userid"])
            )```

Comment: Could probably also note that print(leaderboard) gives a "_default" at the start, like

{'_default': {'1': {'money': 0, 'userid': 820839140111155200}, '10': {'money': 0,  'userid': 435960160624705547}}}

Ill add that to my question.